# How to convert value inside functional component based on generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-tsx

I have the following component:

```
// ...

type StringOrNumber = string | number;

type InputProps<T extends StringOrNumber> = {
  value: T;
  onSubmit: (value: T) => void;
};

export default function Input<T extends StringOrNumber>(props: InputProps<T>) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value.toString());

  // Called on enter & blur
  const submitValue = () => {
    //  ts(2345): Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
    props.onSubmit(value);
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <input
      {/* ... */}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

The reason for the error above inside `submitValue` is quite obvious as `value` is always of type `string` here, whilst `onSubmit` expects a `string` or a `number`, depending on the generic `T` of the component.

The problem is, that I don't know how to properly work around this error. I tried using type guards but that resulted in the same errors:

```
function isNumber(x: StringOrNumber): x is number {
  return typeof x === 'number';
}

// ...

export default function Input<T extends StringOrNumber>(props: InputProps<T>): JSX.Element {
  // ...
  const submitValue = () => {
    if (isNumber(props.value)) {
      const numberValue = parseFloat(value) || 0;
      //  ts(2345): Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      props.onSubmit(numberValue);
    } else {
      //  ts(2345): Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
    props.onSubmit(value);
    }
  };
  // ...
}
```

I guess the issue is that the type guard is only checking the type of `props.value` here whilst it should somehow check what param type `onSubmit` actually expects.

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `extends StringOrNumber` where `StringOrNumber` is `string | number` allows *subtypes* of `string` and `number` as well as those two types. String literal types are subtypes of `string`, and numeric literal types are subtypes of `number`. So even if you convert to `string`, you may not satisfy the constraint on `T` which could be more specific than that (the string literal type `"example"`, for instance).

Your component *can't* correctly convert based on a generic type argument in the general case. So, three options for you:

1. A fairly pragmatic, but technically incorrect, type assertion.
2. Accept a conversion function in the props as well.
3. Use a discriminated union instead of a generic, so there are always exactly two possibilities: `string` and `number`.

#### A fairly pragmatic, but technically incorrect, type assertion

#1 looks like this but is, again, technically incorrect:

```typescript
// Called on enter & blur
const submitValue = () => {
    if (typeof props.value === "string") {
        props.onSubmit(String(value) as T);
    } else {
        props.onSubmit((parseFloat(value) || 0) as T);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYkBfOAMyghDgCIpUMmBuAKC5gE8wSOKSjAAdgHMA8lAByeEACMkUOAF44BGKMlwAPnDELlUbrwFCAkmLB4YABXpgCAHgAqcJAA8KYgCYEwtri0nLGKgB86rhccHFwAG4oADZ4SABccG7c8XAQYsR4iiDAMJkAFEmpGVkAlOpRCRDAftyUZt6QsHB+SDQoeMnwNHhiGMD5cNa2MO6ePkj+gSIhMvJKkeVgTgSZ03aOEM7uEfU4sfFo+VpwANpVadhEMABqKWkAutGEJGQUWzsAHQPJCAmAQFaScq1WpmXIAenhcAAwilkkg-HkxJ4xBRVAAyOCKVJQC5xK5iG4EIolV7vIQaaENGK5XLAGhwcr8QQQDnbI4EYH09RqDRMLQ6CRMM5k1m5fnOQH5QrFUrlSESSr0+ooQJuWGy3LUJDJIgsuWshWC5U0tVbFBQIgAMWSEHIWuq9T0BgADDq9QaLXBKLL2jwEUjAVHw-FWDA8FBseVDRaXOIZimg3EcPCAFRwKOAuC5+EhrMW-LIgAWKEkSDUOHKSHqaiizze1SbYIdEiQMCFnrL5dZIIbIKHw-i8IimbgBpDQA)

#### Accept a conversion function

#2 looks like this:

```typescript
type InputProps<T extends StringOrNumber> = {
    value: T;
    onSubmit: (value: T) => void;
    convert: (value: string) => T;
};

// ...and then when calling `onSubmit`...

const submitValue = () => {
    props.onSubmit(props.convert(value));
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYkBfOAMyghDgCIpUMmBuAKC5gE8wSOKSjAAdgHMA8lAByeEACMkUOAF44BGKMlwAPnDELlUbrwFCAkmLB4YABXpgCAHgAqcJAA8KYgCYEwtri0nLGKgB86rhccHFwAG4oADZ4SABccG7c8XAQYsR4iiDAMJkAFEmpGVkAlOpRCRDAfjnxaPkJKmVwlSlpmVo6EvVqUdlclGbekLBwfkg0KHjJ8DR4YhjA+XDWtjDunj5I-oEiITLySpHlYE4EmXt2jhDO7hH1OLHt+VpwANpVNLYIgwABq-SQAF1ooQSGQKLd7gA6IFIZEwCDnSTlWq1My5AD0hLgAGEUskkH48mJPGIKKoAGRwRSpKDfOIdMR-AhFErgyHRXENGK5XJ3V4EZH5QrFUpIyXIrldWB9ap4tpxKY8Ikk5H6nXxVgwPBQWnlDli3IucT7S1Wq04QkAKjg+uRcGdhMo9oduXypIAFihJEg1DhykhRlFQRDqpGMSgoBIkDBUZDaj6-X60eG0Vns1bCRFfXF8ZMuEA)

*(Or you could just make `onSubmit` accept `string` and do the conversion internally.)*

#### Use a discriminated union

#3 looks like this:

```typescript
type InputProps =
    {
        __type__: "string",
        value: string;
        onSubmit: (value: string) => void;
    }
    |
    {
        __type__: "number",
        value: number;
        onSubmit: (value: number) => void;
    };

// ...and the component function wouldn't be generic anymore:
export default function Input(props: InputProps) {
// ...

// ...and then when calling `onSubmit`...

const submitValue = () => {
    if (props.__type__ === "string") {
        props.onSubmit(String(value));
    } else {
        props.onSubmit((parseFloat(value) || 0));
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYkBfOAMyghDgCIpUMmBuAKC5gE8wSOKSjAAdgHMA8lAByeEACMkUOAF44BGKMlwAPnDELlUbrwFCAkmLB4YABXpgC6rnHe43H7wH0f-QT8ALmYtHQkmTC9vdwA3FAAbPCQQsPEJbhiPCDFiPEUQYBgQgAp4pJTNbXSASnUAPjhYiGAAE0yPSmj9bpxu338LYOYjJRVI-o9y5JDRkw6snLyCotLpyrmVOrVG5raFuEozJAAPSFg4VqQaFDwE+Bo8MQxgHLhrWxgSsCcCEI+7I4IM46n1vGgclo4ABtdbYIgwABqiWSAF11HBCCQyBRvr8AHTrfEwCAidIlGo1MzeAD0NLgAGFEgkkK04G8kGIKKoAGRwRRJKDdCFiKEEfKFJEooQaCkNTxZdzAGhwPHAgj4vwBJB+dRqDRMNKSJigyZZH7q-FLCVFEpkyRlaWUg7eahIBJEBWK7wW5xW3I2r7fFBQIgAMQSEHIjoqdT0BgADM6zYdukceLT6fjsxmPKwYHgoGJVSnvAAecSfUuKnA0gBUcGz+LgdZpXW93pyDIAFihJEg1DgSkhto0EciKsPiSGJEgYISne2O1l1oP1kvl7T6imqVxKEA)

Comment: FYI I went with the discriminated union as it seems like the "most technically correct" thing **and** gives me further flexibility. E.g. I could add properties which are only required by the number type etc. Thank you very much for listing all options in such detail!

Comment: My pleasure! Yeah, despite being third on the list, it's my first choice too. :-)